# Error: Segmentation Fault 11 in Palindrome

Tags: c

So I have been trying to make sure that I can check whether an user-inputted word is a palindrome or not by using function prototypes. However, I am getting an error in the end saying "Segment Fault: 11". I am fairly new to using function prototypes so if anyone can help me with solving anything that can be going on in the body of the function definition, then please point it out to me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void palindrome_check(int ch_length, char text)

int main(void)
{
    int length;
    printf("Enter how many characters are in the message: ");
    scanf("%d", &length);

    char m;
    printf("Enter the message: ");
    scanf("%c", &text);

    palindrome_check(l, m);

    return 0;
}

void palindrome_check(int ch_length, char text)
{
    char msg[ch_length];
    text = msg[ch_length];

    int count = 0;

    while (count < ch_length)
    {
        count++;
        scanf("%c", &msg[count]);
    }

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < ch_length; i++)
    {
        msg[j] = msg[ch_length - i];
    }

    if (text[i] == text[j])
    {
        printf("The message you entered is a palindrome!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("It's not a palindrome.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `text` in main? And are you sure you want to check *a single character* instead of a string? And do add a semi-colon after the declaration of `palindrome_check` near the top. There's too much wrong in the listed code to be able to help you; this would likely won't even compile, and will show a large set of warnings that you need to resolve first.

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon after `void palindrome_check(int ch_length, char text)` at the top of the file.

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Comment: This does not appear to be legal code, but if we suppose that it's a bad copy of your real code (which compiles and runs for a while), then I'll go out on a limb and guess that you're fumbling the count somewhere and reading or writing past the end of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't understand some of your code it seemed you were doing some unnecessary things. What was `msg` for? This should work if I understood your problem correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void palindrome_check(int ch_length, char text []);

int main(void)
{
    char text [100];
    /*
    int length;
    printf("Enter how many characters are in the message: ");
    scanf("%d", &length);
    Not necessary if you use strlen()*/

    printf("Enter the message: ");
    fgets(text,100,stdin); /*Using fgets() to allow spaces input*/
    /*Strip the newline*/
    text [strlen(text)-1]='\0';

    palindrome_check(strlen(text),text);

    return 0;
}

void palindrome_check(int ch_length, char text [])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ch_length; i++)
    {
      if(text [i] != text [ch_length-i-1])
      {
        printf("It's not a palindrome.\n");
        return;
      }
    }
    printf("It is a palindrome!\n");
}
```